# How do I store values from textbox in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I created this program to get texts from textboxes and store in a xml file but it doesn't store. Also if I close the form and reopen it and enter data again how can it update the same existing file without replacing the previous data.? please fix my code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = this.txtName.Text;
        string occupation = this.txtOccupation.Text;
        string dob = this.txtDob.Text;
        string nic = this.txtNic.Text;
        double id = double.Parse(this.lblID.Text);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");

        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Users");
        XmlNode subNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Users");

        XmlAttribute nameAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
        nameAtt.Value = name;
        XmlAttribute occupationAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Occupation");
        occupationAtt.Value = occupation;
        XmlAttribute dobAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Date of Birth");
        dobAtt.Value = dob;
        XmlAttribute nicAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("NIC");
        nicAtt.Value = nic;
        XmlAttribute idAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("ID");
        idAtt.Value = idAtt.ToString();

        subNode.Attributes.Append(nameAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(occupationAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(dobAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(nicAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(idAtt);

        rootNode.AppendChild(subNode);
        subNode.AppendChild(rootNode);

        xmlDoc.Save("E:/Data.xml");
        Hide();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "update the same existing file without replacing the previous data" Among other places, you will need to explain what you mean by that apparent contradiction.

Comment: for example: there is a file data.xml and in that there is a name ALI if I again put entry in the form and enter a name Bradley is should be ALI *new line* Bradley *new line* another name *new line* another name*

Comment: An XML file is a complex structure, if you want to add data to it using standar mechanism first read the previous stored file and then append data to it and save, you're just saving your new document so this is overwriting the old data.

Comment: Gusman can you please make a code for your method?

Comment: `Gusman can you please make a code for your method` Come on @Gusman don't be lazy. write his code :)

Comment: Yeah @Ali, of course, and if you want just tell me what should your program do and I will finish it for you. If you don't want to program and don't know what you're doing hire a real programer. Don't be lazy and at least search for info on how to load a xml...

Comment: @Ali this is not a code servicing site.. you need to write your own code as well as understand how XML works as well as differs from a standard TextFIle..

Comment: @Gusman. it should take the input from textboxes and store them in a file. And when I reopen the form and input data in textboxes it should store in the same file but below the previous record. And also I should be able to read and search from that file.

Comment: .... really?? this is real or a joke??? do you understand english???? ROFL

Comment: @Gusman You got the specs... Start.....

Comment: @MethodMan I did try to learn and make a code for it but couldn't succeed!

Comment: Ok, i'm going to print this post and print it in a poster to put it on my room as the flag of lazyness XD

Comment: @Gusman my english is weak sorry!

Comment: @Ali, if you want to append to your XML you wouldnt have names under names under names in the same node.  take a look at this link [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUw-aTOwAw8 which will help you wiht the basics of XML

Comment: Ok, for your sake it was SARCASM, if you are trying to learn to program and don't succeed then maybe programing is not for you.

Comment: @Gusman I think, but you can help me right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple working example based on the code you provided, but probably there are better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = this.txtName.Text;
    string occupation = this.txtOccupation.Text;
    string dob = this.txtDob.Text;
    string nic = this.txtNic.Text;
    double id = double.Parse(this.lblID.Text);

    // XML file path.
    string xmlPath = "E:/Data.xml";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    // If specified file does not exist, create a new one.
    if (!File.Exists(xmlPath))
    {
        XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
        XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        xmlDoc.InsertAfter(xmlDeclaration, rootNode);

        XmlNode parentNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Users");
        XmlNode subNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("User");

        XmlAttribute nameAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
        nameAtt.Value = name;
        XmlAttribute occupationAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Occupation");
        occupationAtt.Value = occupation;
        XmlAttribute dobAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Date_Of_Birth");
        dobAtt.Value = dob;
        XmlAttribute nicAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("NIC");
        nicAtt.Value = nic;
        XmlAttribute idAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("ID");
        idAtt.Value = id.ToString();

        subNode.Attributes.Append(nameAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(occupationAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(dobAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(nicAtt);
        subNode.Attributes.Append(idAtt);

        xmlDoc.AppendChild(parentNode);
        parentNode.AppendChild(subNode);

        // Save new XML file.
        xmlDoc.Save(xmlPath);
    }
    // If specified file exists, read and update it.
    else
    {
        // Open existing XML file.
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlPath);

        // Set to true if current name is already found in the XML file,
        // of course it should be better to check the ID instead the name,
        // supposing that ID is unique.
        bool nameFound = false;

        // Get all "User" nodes and check if one of them already contains
        // the specified name.
        foreach (XmlNode user in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Users/User"))
        {
            if (user.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value == name)
            {
                nameFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If the name is not already in the file, insert a new user
        // with that name.
        if (nameFound == false)
        {
            XmlNode subNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("User");

            XmlAttribute nameAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
            nameAtt.Value = name;
            XmlAttribute occupationAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Occupation");
            occupationAtt.Value = occupation;
            XmlAttribute dobAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Date_Of_Birth");
            dobAtt.Value = dob;
            XmlAttribute nicAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("NIC");
            nicAtt.Value = nic;
            XmlAttribute idAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("ID");
            idAtt.Value = id.ToString();

            subNode.Attributes.Append(nameAtt);
            subNode.Attributes.Append(occupationAtt);
            subNode.Attributes.Append(dobAtt);
            subNode.Attributes.Append(nicAtt);
            subNode.Attributes.Append(idAtt);

            xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Users").AppendChild(subNode);

            xmlDoc.Save(xmlPath);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a sample output XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Users>
  <User Name="John" Occupation="student" Date_Of_Birth="1990" NIC="NIC" ID="123" />
  <User Name="David" Occupation="professor" Date_Of_Birth="1973" NIC="NIC" ID="452" />
</Users>
```

Comment: @Ali: If this answer solved your issue, you should mark it as an accepted answer (click the check-mark on top-left side of the answer). This is the proper way of saying "thank you" in Stack Overflow ; ).